# Momentjs utc() working differently on local (Mac) and server (Ubuntu)

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Trying to figure out if this is an actual bug or a fundamental gap in understanding moment.js utc() method on my part.

When the method is used to convert an existing time/date string it returns an incorrect result on Ubuntu only

using moment@2.22.2

On Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

```
> moment().utc().format()
'2018-11-10T16:30:28Z'
> moment('2018-11-13 19:00:00').utc().format()
'2018-11-13T19:00:00Z'
```

On Mac OsX 10.13.2

```
> moment().utc().format()
'2018-11-10T16:29:24Z'
> moment('2018-11-13 19:00:00').utc().format()
'2018-11-14T00:00:00Z'
```

Comment: Should use the format argument of `moment(input, format)` when you use a non standard ISO date string

Comment: thnk u but unfortunately, format option doesn't solve this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moment interprets your string as a *local* time. Your Ubuntu machine's time zone is set to UTC, so it reads "2018-11-13 19:00:00" as a UTC time, and converting it to UTC in your code is a noop. Your Mac is on your local time, so it interprets the string as having been expressed in whatever time zone you're in, and then `utc()` translates it to UTC time. So you get different results.

If you want Moment to know that the string is expressed in UTC, you need to tell it that, for example by using ISO's "Z" (e.g. '2018-11-13T19:00:00Z') or by using `moment.utc("2018-11-13 19:00:00", format)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to provide the format in which data string is

```
console.log(moment('2018-11-13 19:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss').utc().format())
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the same behavior persists. Correct date/time on Mac and Ubuntu just passing a date/time through

Comment: ubuntu is still returning the same date/time 

> console.log(moment('2018-11-13 19:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss').utc().format()) 

2018-11-13T19:00:00Z

Comment: @dima Didn't have ubuntu unable to debug this.